# Gunicorn `Can't connect to ('ind', 8000)` - Django, EC2, Nginx

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

This seemed to be working earlier today, I don't know what changed. I'm very inexperienced with deployment, so it could be the simplest thing that I'm missing.

I'm using the default Amazon Linux image on EC2. In a freshly created instance, here are the commands entered:

```
yum search python34 #Amazon Linux doesn't have 3.5 yet
sudo yum install python34-virtualenv
sudo alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3.4
virtualenv-3.4 env
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
hash -r
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/bin/pip

sudo pip install django
django-admin.py startproject MyApp
cd MyApp
python manage.py runserver #This gives me ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in Chrome on port 8000, but worked earlier

sudo yum install nginx
sudo service nginx start #This works, I'm able to see the default page on default port
sudo service nginx stop

sudo pip install gunicorn
gunicorn -bind 0.0.0.0:8000 MyApp.wsgi:application #This doesn't even start
```

Here are the results from the last command:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-48-233 MyApp]$ gunicorn -bind 0.0.0.0:8000 MyApp.wsgi:application
[2015-11-20 19:16:36 +0000] [2547] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
[2015-11-20 19:16:36 +0000] [2547] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-11-20 19:16:37 +0000] [2547] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-11-20 19:16:38 +0000] [2547] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-11-20 19:16:39 +0000] [2547] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-11-20 19:16:40 +0000] [2547] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-11-20 19:16:41 +0000] [2547] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('ind', 8000)
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-48-233 MyApp]$
```

I'm quite lost right now, couldn't find much up-to-date resources to guide me through the details of this process. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The parameter is `-b` or `--bind`, not `-bind`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the root of this problem, for me anyway.  When in the shell that has gunicorn running, exit with ctrl c instead of ctrl z.  After that no hunting for pid's to close. 
good luck Overflowers

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
pgrep gunicorn
```

It will return you the pid, something like this:

```
23716
23718
```

Now kill any one of them using:

```
kill 23716
```

You can recheck using `pgrep gunicorn` if it's still running and kill accordingly.